# Creating a collection of a particular property of all the elements of a collection without iterating the elements of that collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a treenode collection as `IEnumerable<treenode>` nodes. Is there any method to create a collection of `treenode.guid` directly from nodes without iterating all the elements?

E.g.:

```
guidcollection nodeguids = nodes.somemethod();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is not - you obviously need to iterate through the collection of nodes if you need some info from each of them. However you can do something like:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> nodeguids = nodes.Select(n => n.Id);
```

This way you do not perform an iteration manually at least. Although implementation of `Select` involves iteration over all the elements of the collection, and it will be done at the moment you will try to use the `nodeguids` collection somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ uses a lazy iterator. So you can create a collection like this...

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode> myCollection = GetTreeNodes();
IEnumerable<Guid> guidCollection = myCollection.Select(tn => tn.Guid);
```

The guidCollection will not be populated until it is iterated, counted, acted upon in some way.

You could also just go old school.

```
function IEnumerable<Guid> GetIdsFromCollection(TreeNode collection)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
        yield return item;
}
```